# Prove that for n ≥ 2 and k ≤ n, ${n \choose k} ≤ \frac{n^k}{2^{k−1}}$

Tags: combinatorics

Is this bound ever tight, meaning does equality ever hold for some n, k?

I am not sure how to proceed with this inequality, any direction will help greatly.

Comment: ${n \choose k} = n(n-1)...(n-k+1)/(k(k-1)...2) \le \frac{n^k}{2^{k-1}}$ with inequality basically never holding, unless $k=1$ or something

Comment: I worked out a few discrete examples, and it seems to hold true?  6 choose 3 = 20, which is less than 6^3/2^2=54.  Am I viewing this incorrectly?

Comment: @user524037 Yes, it always holds.  I think mathworker21 meant to say that *equality* never holds unless $k=1$

Comment: I am sorry, I misinterpreted!

Answer (score 0):

A simple set of inequalities for $n!$:
$n! \ge 2^{n-1}$;
for $n \ge 3$,
$n! \ge 2\cdot 3^{n-2}$;
for $n \ge m$,
$n! \ge m!\cdot (m+1)^{n-m}$.

Proof:
$n!
=\prod_{k=1}^n k
=(\prod_{k=1}^m k)( \prod_{k=m+1}^n k)
\ge m! (m+1)^{n-m}
$.

For $m=1$ this is
$n! \ge 2^{n-1}$.

For $m=2$ this is
$n! \ge 2\cdot 3^{n-2}$.

We have

$\binom{n}{k}
=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)}{k!}
\le\dfrac{n^k}{m!(m+1)^{k-m}}
$
for
$k > m$.

For $m=1$,
this is your inequality.

If we use
$n! > (n/e)^n$
(proved here a number of times),
then

$\binom{n}{k}
=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)}{k!}
\le\dfrac{n^k}{(k/e)^k}
=(en/k)^k
$
and this is stronger
for $k \ge 2e$
or $k \ge 6$.

Comment: Sorry to ask, this is quite new to me.  Can you tell me about "e"? I am unsure how to follow the last two lines.

Comment: $e$ is Euler's constant. $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/n! = 2.71828...$.